# Improper reputation points showing in notification and answer

Tags: support, down-votes, notifications

I just saw my Stack Overflow account after 5 hours. Previously it was showing 30 reputation points for today and upvotes in all of the three answers (I do not consider marks now) in the below image:

[image]

But as you see, there are +8 reputation points in the first answer of the above image, I have not received any downvote notification till now, and also there is no downvote in the answer either. Please check the image below.

[image]

[Link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175603/how-can-i-append-an-id-to-href/39175626#39175626)

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there's both an upvote and a downvote on the answer (which is why the score is 0). They've happened in close proximity to each other, so it's displaying **+8** (+10 for upvote, -2 for downvote).

Working as designed.

Comment: but no notification of the downvote yet?

Comment: Since they've happened so close to one another, they're combined in the one notification. That's why it says +8 in your notification.

Answer (score 5):

As Al E. says in their answer, the purpose of the "achievements" bar is not to give you a detailed breakdown of votes. (Although you *can* often deduct it from the numbers.)

Please note that if you want a *detailed*, unambigious breakdown of your upvotes versus downvotes, you can see it in the [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3964601/nalin-aggarwal?tab=reputation) tab of your profile.

[image]